# Laravel Validation for Multiple input values

Tags: laravel, laravel-validation

I am working on the Laravel Validation code. In my code, I used the radio button for three options like approve, reject, and return. In the Remarks textbox, validation depends on the Radio button values. Without choosing any options, the validation is working fine, like "Please choose any one." If I choose the Approve option, then the Remarks textbox validation shows an error like "Please enter remarks for your approval". If I choose the Reject Option, it shows an error like "Please enter remarks for rejection."

```
<input type="radio" id="approve" name="radiooption" value="-1">
<input type="radio" id="reject" name="radiooption" value="R">
<input type="radio" id="return" name="radiooption" value="A">
<input type="text" value = "Remarks" name = "remarks" >



$validated = $request->validate([            
            'radiooption'   => ['required'],
            'remarks' =>  ['required_if:radiooption',-1,'A','R']
            ]
            [
            'radiooption.required' => 'Please choose one of the action.',
            'remarks.required_if' => 'Please enter reason(s) to applicant :values',
```

]

Above is not working, It shows error like **Validation rule required_if requires at least 2 parameters.** Please support me to solve that issue

Comment: The code is not working

Comment: How should it work instead? Please post that information in your question.

Comment: Sidenote, you're using `id="radiooption"` 3 times, but ids need to be unique, or use `class="radiooption"` instead. No effect on your current issue (which is a syntax error on usage of `required_if`: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/validation#rule-required-if), but if you ever tried to target `document.getElementById('radiooption')`, you'd run into issues.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for your validation seems incorrect, required_if can take multiple values to check against the field. While the usage of `|` seems incorrect, normally the values would be separated in the string like this `required|string`,  you are doing it outside the string.

```
 'remarks' => ['required_if:radiooption,1,2,3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Like mentioned in the comments above, You've mixed up your attributes on your input tags. Each radio button should have the same name (`radiooption` in this case). Where as the id's should be unique.

Once that is fixed, using @mrhn's answer above will also be required.